# How can I include unix path information in a rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application which needs to handle path information (it will be working with files on the server). Here is how I'm trying to do the route.

```
match "viewfile/file=:vFile" => "home#viewfile"
```

and here is how I'm trying to link to the file

```
link_to("file",
       { :controller => "home", :action => "viewfile", :vFile => "/this/is/a/test" })
```

This, however, throws errors and does not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace? The syntax with characters like `=` and `:` seems suspect to me.

Comment: @mliebelt This is standard ruby on rails syntax.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html But, I'll add the trace anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to("file", { ... url_encode("/this/is/a/test/") })
```

Is more likely to work.

Comment: The equal sign isn't causing any issues. If I change the test path to "thisIsATest" it is routed correctly. The presence of a forward slash in the URL is the issue here.

Comment: Ah, I'll remove the equal sign note then. Glad you got it working. There's some characters that don't seem to work well in routes, I thought equal sign was one of them.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the routing does not know which route to match because multiple routes could match your controller/action/vFile combination, so name the route like:

```
match "viewfile/file=:vFile" => "home#viewfile", :as => 'viewfile'
```

now you can use the `viewfile_path` helper

```
link_to 'file', viewfile_path("/this/is/a/test")
```

PS: I don't know if it works with the equal (=) sign in the url, what definitely works is:

```
match "viewfile/file/:vfile" => "home#viewfile", :as => 'viewfile'
link_to 'file', viewfile_path("/this/is/a/test")
```

but give it a try...